# Audio will play in 3.2 sim but not in 4.x

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, audio-streaming

This streaming audio app will play in 3.2 simulator, but not in 4.x sim or my 4.1 iPhone.
The console logs are as follows:

```
4.0 Sim

This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".Attaching to process 13237.
[Switching to process 13237]
2010-11-15 19:54:49.606 Issues[13237:1c07] AddRunningClient starting device on non-zero client count
2010-11-15 19:55:16.220 Issues[13237:6307] AQMEIO_Base::DoStartIO: timeout
2010-11-15 19:55:16.498 Issues[13237:6307] AQMEDevice::StartIO: error -66681
2010-11-15 19:55:16.499 Issues[13237:6307] CA_UISoundClientBase::StartPlaying: AddRunningClient failed (status = -66681).
2010-11-15 19:55:46.499 Issues[13237:1c07] AQMEIO_Base::DoStartIO: timeout
2010-11-15 19:55:46.777 Issues[13237:1c07] AQMEDevice::StartIO: error -66681
2010-11-15 19:55:46.778 Issues[13237:1c07] Audio queue start failed. err: ˇ˛˚á -66681
[Switching to process 13237]

4.1 Device

This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys001
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-11399-40
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
[Switching to thread 11523]
[Switching to thread 11523]
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
[Switching to thread 13059]
[Switching to thread 11523]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it makes you feel better, I have had this exact problem for a couple weeks with no solution in sight. I think it occurred when I upgraded my ipad to 4.2 but I am not sure. I was still able to use the 3.2 simulator for my music app testing, but now I have been making my app universal and there is no way to test the iphone code on the simulator.

EDIT: I fixed it!!

The only other google search result for this error led me to poke around in my audio settings. I have a Blackmagic Intensity Pro HDMI capture card and it was set as my audio input device. I changed it to "Line in" or whatever, restarted my Mac, and then the simulator worked again!

I was also messing around with my audio output settings, so it's hard to know for sure what actually solved it, but the key is: mess around with your audio settings, restart your Mac and cross your fingers.

one more edit: I had this same problem occur with a webcam on my other, work computer. I changed the audio from the input of the web cam back to line in, and it worked again. How are more people not seeing this?

Comment: I set my audio input to Line In and disconnected my Snowball mic and it fixed this for me.

Comment: Looks like an audio routing issue.  I have same problem (I run dragon dictate & have USB soundcard).  Reboot fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and fixed it by unplugging an external microphone which was hooked up via USB. Not sure why this fixed it, but it did.

Answer (score 1):

I have the problem too, but i fixed it in some minutes, thank to Ethical. Although the problem is same, my code is different, my code supplie in the video player. My code run good in the ipad/iphone device, but not in simulator. When the video start playing, the simulator freezon, the output is like you, but i remember i plug in the earphone just now, and pull out some miniutes later, so the setting of audio player changed, i think. So, i plug in the earphone again and restart my mac. The problem solved. So just restart your mac, or check the setting of audio player.

Answer (score 1):

+1 .... Checking and changing the Mac's **audio input** also worked for me. I had no sound in the simulator (Mac Pro) but my app worked fine on the device (iPad 3) calling

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"soundname.caf"];
```

In the sim, there was a long lag after first trying to play a sound (my app seemed to hang, with high CPU usage). After a long time it would give a `AQMEIO_Base::DoStartIO: timeout` error and the app would resume, albeit without sound. Happened every time I ran it.

The sound output was shown as line out, but **sound input** was set to **digital**. Changing the input to **line in** made sound work in the simulator.

There is still a cascade of warnings in the sim on startup, starting with:

> Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

and ending in

Default audio device changed. Restart the simulator to have it use the newly-selected device.

But sound now works and I can test the app using the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play your audio on MPMovidePlayerController instead of MPMediaPlayer