# simulator running prob-iphone sdk

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

When I run my app I got this error ans quit application. I used 4.0 and 4.1 simulator. Please help me any one.....

```
2011-05-16 17:13:59.113 Dragon-Kish[15784:9303] AQMEIO_Base::DoStartIO: timeout
2011-05-16 17:13:59.114 Dragon-Kish[15784:9303] AQMEDevice::StartIO: error -66681
2011-05-16 17:13:59.114 Dragon-Kish[15784:9303] CA_UISoundClientBase::StartPlaying: AddRunningClient failed (status = -66681).
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190732/audio-will-play-in-3-2-sim-but-not-in-4-x

Comment: Can you post the code for the AudioRunningClient and StartPlaying method, or just the code for the audio.

Comment: An error message without documentation of your code is almost impossible to troubleshoot. You need to post relevant code if you want an answer.